# Setting value to a hiddenField in html2canvas event

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, html2canvas

I have a problem with setting value to a hiddentfield in html2canvas onrendered event.

Here is my code snippets:

js:

```
function saveCanvas()
{
    var data = null;
    html2canvas([document.getElementById('hidTest')],
    {
        onrendered: function(canvas)
        {
            data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            alert(data);
            jQuery("input[name='hid']").val(data);
            alert(jQuery('#hid').val());
        }
    });
    alert(data);
}
```

html:

```
...
<g:hiddenField name="hid"/>
...
```

What I note is that the alert outside the onrendered event will fire as first. Also in alert(data) in onrendered event I see that data is create corectly, but it isn't assign to the hiddenField (hid), and "alert(jQuery('#hid').val())" shows me that my hiddenField is undefined. I will be very grateful for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution. I think jQuery is too slow? And pure js works fine:

instead of this:

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById('hidTest')],
{
    onrendered: function(canvas)
    {
        data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        jQuery("input[name='hid']").val(data);
    }
});
```

I use this:

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById('hidTest')],
{
    onrendered: function(canvas)
    {
        var dataBind = document.getElementById('hid');
        data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        dataBind.value = data;
    }
});
```

## Edit

It's a bit strange but something like this also works fine:

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById('hidTest')],
{
    onrendered: function(canvas)
    {
        jQuery("input[name='hid']").val(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    }
});
```